# PyCharm giving exit code 0 before accepting input

Tags: python-3.x

I am following along a Udemy course for Python. The second input function is allowing the instructor to enter an input, but it goes straight to end without errors when I attempt to run.

Below is the code I am trying to run and it's been copied exactly as it is displayed in the video:

```
_author_ = 'dev'
name = input("Please enter your name: ")
age = input("How old are you, {0}?".format(name))
print(age)
```

Output:

```
Please enter your name:K. Clark
How old are you, K. Clark?
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Maybe an issue with my PyCharm settings?

Any answer is welcome.

Comment: Judging by the formatting of your output (I'm assuming you copy/pasted exactly), it seems there are extra linebreaks between the first and second inputs, which would lead to the second input being empty. Now I don't know what could be causing this. You could be double tapping enter after input, it could be a pycharm thing, a linefeed/carriage return thing.

Comment: I think you are correct, I pasted my code into the python console instead of viewing in the run window and it works as intended. Thanks for your response!